# AncestorNotifier fires the event AncestorAdded twice

Tags: java, swing, events, listener

I've added a AncestorListener to my component and found the following problem:
Everytime when the component is shown, the method ancestorAdded(AncestorEvent event) is called twice. Once the event is fired from the method AncestorNofifier.componentShown and once from the method AncestorNotifier.propertyChange.

```
addAncestorListener(new AncestorListener() {
      @Override
      public void ancestorAdded(AncestorEvent event) {
        //do sth.
      }

      @Override
      public void ancestorRemoved(AncestorEvent event) {
         //do sth.
      }

      @Override
      public void ancestorMoved(AncestorEvent event) {
        //not used
      }
    });
```

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know how to prevent one of these envents?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why this would be a problem. It sounds like one event goes to your AncestorLIstener and the other goes to the PropertyChange listener. So you would only listen for one of the events. Post your [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Hello camickr,
thank you for the quick answer.
I have changed my question a little bit.
Perhaps you can look through it?

Comment: Again I don't understand the problem. There is nothing to look at. This is the way the internals of the event handling work. The event may me generated, but if you have no listeners then nothing happens. You still haven't posted an [mcve].